# Prevent pull requests into staging from all branches but dev

Tags: git, github

I always accidentally push from my temporary feature branch straight into staging so my dev branch is outdated. Is there a way I can allow pull requests into staging only from the dev branch? Or at least set the default pull request branch for all temporary feature branches to be dev?

Comment: Git itself has no rules about pull requests, because pull requests themselves are a GitHub add-on. GitHub (the add-on stuff they provide, that is) *does*, so that's probably the avenue to pursue. Git does allow you to write your own *pre-push hooks* (locally in your repository) and you could perhaps write one that prevents you from doing the push you wish to prevent yourself from doing, though.

Comment: @torek let me know if you did about my answer mention. And tell me if was useful.

Comment: @mononoke83: I hadn't seen your answer when I posted my comment. It does look useful though.

Comment: @torek Sorry for the late answer. Even tho stackoverflow for some reason put "git" in front of my question (only in search) I ment github

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set some protection branch rules or setting your branches according to this:

[Creating a branch protection rule](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule#creating-a-branch-protection-rule)